# Transition between views by navigation controller. ignoring tabbarcontroller

Tags: c#, objective-c, xcode, xamarin.ios, xamarin

There is a problem , I have one available repose collection `ViewController`. At the same representation have a button switch to another `View`. Between the repose organized transitions (navigation controller). Clicking on the back button in the second presentation is called `ViewDidAppear` is good. But I also have an application has `tabBarController`. And when you click on the first `View` on the panel `tabBar` called again `ViewDidAppear`. Although he no longer needs to be called . Tell me how can I do so that does not cause tabbar `ViewDidAppear`. A caused only `navigationController`? Thank you!

Comment: Please share some code with us that how you are managing it.

Comment: The fact that there is almost no code is used. Everything is done in xcode, storyboard. Only used this code: public override void ViewDidAppear. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: public override void ViewDidLayout like. But fires twice

Answer (score 0):

ViewDidAppear will be called every time a ViewController is displayed is shown on the screen.

ViewDidLoad is called only when the View is loaded. So for example, if you present a modal view from a view controller (parent vc), then when the modal is dismissed, the parent vc will NOT have its ViewDidLoad method called. Instead it will have ViewWillAppear and ViewDidApper called only.

Moving the code you only want called once to ViewDidLoad should solve your problem.